# AWS presigned URL upload slow

Tags: amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

When i upload 2.2mb image size to s3 via presigned URL , It's unbelievable take 22 second to AWS S3
[like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyIX4.png),

But when i'm using Nodejs to upload same image by AWS SDK , just take 8 second

Is there some config problem ?

I don't know how to solve this problem...[nodejs image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suQQT.png)

Comment: Try logging the underlying API calls to see if it's hitting a different endpoint. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/logging-sdk-calls.html